# Распаковка Yii средствами yiic webapp

Tags: framework, yii

Вот я скачал yii фреймворк

Положил в папку www папку framework - теперь как быть дальше?

Я запутался в том что допустим в одном видео говорят что распаковывать нужно в папку www, но в тоже время в самом фреймворке идут примеры которые распиханы по папкам.

А еще я видел вариант с папкой фронтенд и бэкенд

Куда вообще правильно его распаковать?  в итоге должен получиться простенький сайт с админкой.

Answer (score 1):

Есть рекомендации не класть в public_html сам фреймворк, так что положить его можете куда угодно, только в файле index.php в корне проекта пропишите этот путь в

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'<path-to-framework>/yii.php';
```

Ну а разделение backend и frontend сугубо дело вкуса, для небольших проектов на мой взгляд проще сделать модуль админки внутри приложения, для больших пожалуй отдельное приложение админки лучше (и в плане безопасности, да и на другой сервер можно вынести, лишь бы базу одну использовали)

Answer (score 0):

Теперь прописать путь к папке "framework"

`$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';`

Comment: похоже вы вопрос дочитали только до 2-й строки

ну или я так его коряво написал

Answer (score 0):

Распаковывайте куда хотите, куда вам удобнее. Я, лично, храню фреймворк в папке /var/lib/yii

Answer (score 0):

можно хранить где угодно, вам всего то нужен системный файл framework внутри архива. сохраните его внутри папки  www и туда же скопируйте папку blog из папки demo всё вроде перезапустите и вуаля!